# difficult to understand drupal hook menu function

Tags: routes, hooks

I am new to drupal.I can't understand how drupal hook menu works.I visit the drupal site and try to read documentation.but it is too difficult to understand.can you please tell me a good tutorial so that I can understand how they work.thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me the best way to get a solid understanding on Drupal **quickly**, was to purchase some video tuition. By watching just a couple of these paid downloads, I had a good understanding on the basics.

Most tutorials step you through building your first custom module, explaining what everything is, why it is required and how it works into the overall structure.

A number of companies offer this type of product, and [this one](http://buildamodule.com/video/drupal-7-core-concepts-how-to-add-and-manipulate-pages-with-the-menu-system-how-the-menu-system-works) is a freebie from one site to introduce the Drupal menu system, including hook_menu()

Comment: ...of course I'd be happy to try and provide some assistance with a specific area you are having trouble with. Just edit your question with more detail about what you are working on and where you are getting stuck. :)